# Can I have Spring Boot create a WebClient which uses OAuth2 without it trying to apply the OAuth flow to my endpoints?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I want to have a WebClient which uses a client_credentials OAuth2 flow to authorize with an API. I've followed various sets of instructions from the documentation to several tutorials.

I feel like I'm pretty close to getting Spring Boot to do what I want, but the default behaviour is doing something I don't want - I get redirected to /login when I make a request to any of my controllers. I want to be able to (at the moment) do an *unauthorized* request to my API, and have the service-to-service call use the configured OAuth2 flow.

```yaml
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: reactive
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          my-private-api:
            client-id: <foo>
            client-secret: <bar>
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
        provider:
          my-private-api:
            token-uri: <uri>
```

```java
    @Bean
    WebClient webClient( final ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations,
        final ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService )
    {
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth =
            new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction( new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                clientRegistrations,
                authorizedClientService ) );
        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId( "my-private-api" );
        return WebClient.builder().filter( oauth ).build();
    }
```

Do I need to do lots of manual configuration in order to avoid this default behaviour I don't want?

Comment: Are your controllers `@RestController` (or `@Controller` with `@RespnseBody`) or does its methids return templates names?

Comment: Is any of that relevant? Ideally I'd also like this to work outside the context of a request (which I did find the section on in the Spring Security docs but it seemed to then not autoconfigure the expected beans)

Comment: Yes it can be relevant. Please give us your definitions of OAuth2 clients and resource-servers and what you want to your Spring app to be to that regard.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out my OAuth configuration was fine, what I was actually asking for was "how do I disable the default behaviour of Spring Security's SecurityWebFilterChain" - which is to add a bean overriding the behaviour:

```java
    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springWebFilterChain( final ServerHttpSecurity http )
    {
        http.httpBasic().disable().formLogin().disable().csrf().disable().logout().disable();
        return http.build();
    }
```